# Finding the 6th Derivative of a function of $\sin(x)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I am currently studying Maclaurin Series, and have come across a question that has me stumped. The function is:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+\sin(x^2)}$$

The question asks me to find the 6th derivative of this function evaluated at $0$. Now I am trying to solve this with a Maclaurin Expansion of $\sin(x)$, but I get:

$$\frac{1}{1+\sin(x^2)} = \frac{1}{1+x^2-\frac{x^6}{6!}+\frac{x^{10}}{5!}}$$

I am struggling to find the 6th derivative, as the coefficient of $x^6$ is not obvious.

Comment: [THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno's_formula) might be of interest, especially with high-order derivatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You're on the right track.

Continuing, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1+\sin(x^2)}&=\frac{1}{1+\left(x^2-\frac16x^6+O\left(x^{10}\right)\right)}\\\\
&=1-\left(x^2-\frac16x^6+O\left(x^{10}\right)\right)+\left(x^2+O\left(x^6\right)\right)^2-\left(x^2+O\left(x^6\right)\right)^3+O(x^8)\\\\
&=1-x^2+x^4-\frac56x^6+O(x^8)
\end{align}$$

> **Therefore, the sixth derivative is $-(5/6)6!=-600$.**

Comment: Hey, Mark ! Good to see you. Please look at my comment to FelicioGrande; I never had the feeling that we compete (at the contrary !)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Hello my friend.  I hope that you're enjoying this holiday season!  And I believe that we support each other in bringing the best answers we can.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you! Much appreciative.

Answer (score 3):

You properly wrote $$\frac{1}{1+\sin(x^2)} = \frac{1}{1+x^2-\frac{x^6}{6!}+\frac{x^{10}}{5!}+O\left(x^{12}\right)}$$ Now perform the long division (by increasing powers of $x$) to get $$\frac{1}{1+\sin(x^2)} = 1-x^2+x^4-\frac{5 x^6}{6}+\frac{2 x^8}{3}-\frac{61
   x^{10}}{120}+O\left(x^{12}\right)$$ Therefore

- the sixth derivative is $-\frac 5 6\times 6!=-600$
- the eighth derivative is $\frac 2 3\times 8!=26880$
- the tenth derivative is $-\frac {61}{120}\times 10!=-1844640$

Comment: Tenacious! (+1)

Comment: This comment is great (+1), but Dr.MV had answered is first, thus my decision to give the checkmark to him. But thank you for this great answer!

Comment: @FelicioGrande. You are perfectly correct ! In any manner, I am not competing with my good friend Dr. MV. I was just proposing a way starting from what you wrote. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Use the geometric series i.e. $$\frac{1}{1 + \sin(x^2)} = 1 + \Big( -x^2 + \frac{x^6}{3!} - \frac{x^{10}}{5!} + ... \Big) + \Big( - x^2 + \frac{x^6}{3!} - \frac{x^{10}}{5!} + ... \Big)^2 + ...$$

Comment: @Dr.MV I think this is enough of a hint for now

Comment: @Dr.MV Of course it's correct. I already took that into account.